# magento 1.9 override core block template

Tags: magento-1.9, module, xml, frontend

I edited these files but I cannot override the default.phtml file, it doesn't work, what's wrong with that?

Config.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Vendor_Mymodule>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Vendor_Mymodule>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <myfile>
                    <file>myfile.xml</file>
                </myfile>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

myfile.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <catalog_product_view> 
        <reference name="product.info.simple">
           <action method="setTemplate">
               <template>mymodule/catalog/product/view/default.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <catalog_product_view> 
        <reference name="product.info.simple">
           <action method="setTemplate">
               <template>catalog/product/view/default.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

the template should be in :

> app/design/frontend/{theme}/{name}/template/catalog/product/view/default.phtml

Comment: I don't want to edit the core file, I want to use a file in my custom path

Comment: Yes ofcourse, but can you tel me where is the core here ?

Comment: It is not the default theme, so if I want to modify only this theme how to achieve that, without edit the file?

Comment: I put `{theme}/{name}` this mean that you replace this with your current theme